# ng g s services/post module=app.module doesn't work in angular 7

Tags: terminal, angular7

I want to create a new service that will already appear in the main app module provider array.
I tried this line in the terminal:

```
ng g s services/post module=app.module
```

and this line as well:

```
ng g s services/post --module=app.module
```

But it doesn't seem to work. Is there alternative that works for angular7 ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
ng g s services/post --module app
```